# How to get the value from json using requests?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I want to retrive all the `"SKU"` values from the `collapseValues` list in the json link mentioned below. Can anyone help me?

link: `https://www.grainger.com/product/tableview/GRAINGER-APPROVED-Square-Head-Plugs-WP7366807&s_pp=false`

My code:

```
x = requests.get(f"grainger.com/product/tableview/…"
for p in x['records']:
    for child in p['children']:
        for item in json.loads(child['collapseValues']):
            url = f"grainger.com/product{item ['sku']}"
            print(url)
```

But an unhelpful `KeyError: 'collapseValues'` occurs.

Comment: You will have to write some code to do that.

Comment: What did you do, for now? give us some information in order to help you. I think a simple search on google might be better than asking a question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @HassanAliSalem x = requests.get(f"https://www.grainger.com/product/tableview/GRAINGER-APPROVED-Square-Head-Plugs-WP7366807&s_pp=false").json()





for p in x['records']:
    for child in p['children']:
        for item in json.loads(child['collapseValues']):
           
                url = f"https://www.grainger.com/product/{item ['sku']}"
                print(url)

Comment: @HassanAliSalem but no helpful get a key error collapseValues

Comment: you should convert x to json first befor looping over it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple loop over json result:

```
import requests
import json

url ="https://www.grainger.com/product/tableview/GRAINGER-APPROVED-Square-Head-Plugs-WP7366807&s_pp=false"


r = requests.get(url)

for records in r.json()["records"]:
    for children in  records["children"]:
        if "collapseValues" in children:
            values = json.loads(children["collapseValues"])
            for val in values:
                print(val["sku"])
```

Output:

```
1UVP9
2KVX4
2KVX5
1UVR4
2KVY3
2KVY4
1UVR2
2KVX8
2KVX9
```

Comment: mate saved me a big time